# Cannot encrypt data with imported public key

Tags: angular, typescript, cryptography

```
async generatePublicAndPrivateKeys(): Promise<CryptoKeyPair> {
    const algorithm: RsaHashedKeyGenParams = {
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      modulusLength: 2048,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
      hash: 'SHA-256',
    };

    return window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(algorithm, true, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);
  }

  async encryptWithPublicKey(publicKey: CryptoKey, data: string): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const encodedData = new TextEncoder().encode(data);

      console.log(publicKey);
      console.log("ENCRYPTING DATA")

      const encryptedData = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        { name: 'RSA-OAEP' },
        publicKey,
        encodedData,
      );

      console.log("END OF ENCRYPTION");

      return this.ab2str(encryptedData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    return "this.ab2str(encryptedData);"
  }

async decryptWithPrivateKey<T>(privateKey: CryptoKey, encryptedData: string): Promise<T>{          
    const decryptedData = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      { name: 'RSA-OAEP' },
      privateKey,
      this.str2ab(encryptedData),
    );

    return JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(decryptedData)) as T;
  }

  async exportKey(key: CryptoKey, pubKey: boolean): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const exportedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        pubKey ? 'spki' : 'pkcs8',
        key,
      );

      const exportedKeyBuffer = new Uint8Array(
        exportedKey,
      ) as unknown as number[];

      const exportedKeyString = btoa(
        String.fromCharCode.apply(null, exportedKeyBuffer),
      );
      return exportedKeyString;
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    return "";
  }




  async importKey(keyString: string, pubKey: boolean): Promise<CryptoKey> {
    try {
      const keyBuffer = Uint8Array.from(atob(keyString), (c) =>
        c.charCodeAt(0),
      ).buffer;

      return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        pubKey ? 'spki' : 'pkcs8',
        keyBuffer,
        {
          name: 'RSA-OAEP',
          hash: { name: 'SHA-256' },
        },
        true,
        pubKey ? ['encrypt'] : ['decrypt'],
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    return new CryptoKey();
  }
```

After generating public and private keys, then sending public key to other client, he cannot encrypt any data with it, due to `(anonymous)` error.

I can encrypt data with public key and decrypt it with private if not exporting and then importing those keys. Public key is transferred from one client to another via @microsoft/signalr without any encryption.

Comment: *...I can encrypt data with public key and decrypt it with private if not exporting and then importing those keys. ...*: Does this mean that if you export and import the public key it does not work? Or in other words: What do I have to do to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The code is not executable, `ab2str()` and `str2ab()` are missing. What kind of encoding/decoding are these functions performing?

Comment: The issue is not reproducible (using own implementations for the missing parts). Even with export and import of the public key, encryption and decryption work: https://jsfiddle.net/4jmbLza8/. Possibly your encoding/decoding functions use a charset encoding. Try a binary-to-text-encoding, e.g. Base64. But that's just a guess, since you didn't post the functions. Please post a complete code with which a repro of the issue is possible, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: First time I've come accross an "anonymous" error.